# Can I delete the folder /debian/dbgtmp (in root)?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I found having a folder called `/debian` in the root folder (`/`) which is 2.5GB of size. It contains a single subfolder called `dbgtmp` that contains several other subfolders.

[image: contents of the /debian folder]

I'm almost sure that they're the remains of my custom kernel compiled because of the [missing touchpad driver from 14.04 stock kernel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1372609).

```
$ uname -a
Linux asus-UX303LA 3.17.2-custom #2 SMP Wed Nov 5 08:59:54 AEDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My question is whether is it to safe to delete that folder or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default hierarchy in a default Linux system:

[image: 1]

As you can see there are no folders named `/debian` . So, as you have stated those are left-overs of your custom kernel compilation. You may delete it to free up some space. But if possible you might want to back-up your system to be on the safe side.

Also, from [free-electrons](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/scripts/package/builddeb?v=3.15), on **line 82** you will see that this type of directory is created in order to generate a deb package for a Linux kernel:

```
dbg_dir="$objtree/debian/dbgtmp"
```

Comment: Correct, deleted it, rebooted and everything works as before. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Glad! It worked!

Comment: Whenever I do such things, I merely rename the directory. If nothing breaks on a restart, usually I just delete it. When I'm not sure, I'll keep it on some backup drive (along with a text file describing where I got the directory from and when I did that) until I forget about it. Then, after some time has passed and I attach that backup drive again, I delete that directory. If I remembered it before, that's because it was important and had to be restored. A kinda lazy approach ;D